# What's the directive that store into an array a list of [] variables

Tags: php

I see on PHP that if I send a list of paramters with the name [], on server side it automatically save these values into an array.

So, for example, if I send values via GET :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="customArray[]" value="1" checked="checked" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="customArray[]" value="2" checked="checked" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="customArray[]" value="3" checked="checked" /> 3
```

I can access on php to that array with $_GET['customArray'].

I'd like to know this behaviour : is it a standart behaviour? Is it piloted by a directive? can I disable/able this? And so on...

I don't like to create my application and know that in some years (maybe) this won't be available anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it's standard behaviour.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

No, you can't disable it.

It will not be made invalid in the future. Or, if it is, it'd likely only be done along with tremendous other changes to the language that would render a lot of your other code broken, too. In short, don't worry about forward compatibility with this feature; it's not going anywhere.

Indeed, it's common-place to use this.

Comment: Yeah I use often this strategy :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an array created, then don't use the `[]` notation in your field names. That'll revert to standard practice where duplicate name fields will overwrite each other, with the last one getting sent being the "winner".

It is standard behavior in PHP. Other languages may or may not honor such a construct. As far as I know, there's no directive to enable this in PHP - it's always present and can't be disabled.

Comment: Yeah..but in fact I want that notation :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this style of data management when you have multiple chceckboxes, for example if you're making some polls, forms, etc. But if you don't want to use the array-style, you can just rename them (`checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3` instead of `checkboxes[] checkboxes[] checkboxes[]`)